# Display results from CoreData using NSPredicate in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: FetchRequest("Teams", key: "team_name"), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
```

and this code in my TableView cellForRowAtIndex:

```
        var cell = teamView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("team_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeamCellSettings

        if let cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Team {
            //create cell here
        }

    return cell
```

I have read online on how to use NSPredicate, but I cannot seem to get it to work. My goal is to use a segmented control to switch between the results displayed in the UITableView based off of the contents of a row's attribute. So if my entity `X` had an attribute named `A`, `A` would store either a 1 or a 0, so basically I need the segmented control to switch between **all** the results containing a 1 in attribute `A` or a 0 in attribute `A`

My creative writing skills are not the best. Hope you can understand my goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The predicate needs to be added to the fetch request, for example:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Your entity name")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "A == %d", 1)
request.predicate = predicate

fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
  fetchRequest: request, 
  managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, 
  sectionNameKeyPath: nil, 
  cacheName: nil)
```

What goes to the predicate depends on your goals. In a next step you will need to update the fetch request and reload the data as you change the selected item in the segmented control. In your `IBAction` that is called when the segmented control changes, get `sender.selectedSegmentIndex` and create the new predicate based on the index. 
The code to refetch will look something like this:
Swift 2

```
        fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "A = %d", some_int_goes_here)
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
        }
        catch {
            fatalError()
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
```

If you do Swift 1.2, omit the error handling, of course, something like this:

```
fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "A = %d", some_int_goes_here)
fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! Your code worked with the predicate issue that I was facing. However could you help me in refetching my request using the segmeted control, since I have tried several ways and the request just won't refetch

Comment: the newly added code is throwing all sorts of errors. telling me to insert a semi colon inbetween 'try' and 'fetchedresultscontroller.performfetch() etc. I'm not sure how to go about using this. I'm using XCode 6.3.

Comment: Right. It is a Swift 2 code. See updates for older versions of Swift in my answer.